# Automapper - Mapping the index into a property of collection

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm mapping a domain model to a DTO and vice versa. I'm trying to configure my API to accept a DTO with a collection, where the order of that collection will map to a `int Sequence` in my domain object for persistence.

```
public class Model {
    public ICollection<Fields> Fields { get; set; }
}
public class Field {
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
}
```

```
CreateMap<ModelView, Model>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Fields, opt => opt...)
    // here I want to specify that currentField.Sequence = Model.Fields.IndexOf(currentField)
    //     , or to set it equal to some counter++;
    ;
```

Is such a thing possible in Automapper, or would I have to write my own `ConstructUsing()` method to do this logic?  I'm hesitant to use `ConstructUsing()` because I have a mapping specified for the Field DTO and I don't want to duplicate that logic.

I also would like to be able to configure it so that when I'm going back to my DTO (`Model` -> `ModelView`) that I can insert the `Field`s into the collection in the order specified by `Sequence`.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the solution I was looking for. Using `AfterMap()` I'm able to override these values from being mapped directly:

```
CreateMap<Model, ModelView>()
    .AfterMap((m, v) =>
    {
        v.Fields = v.Fields?.OrderBy(x => x.Sequence).ToList(); 
        //ensure that the DTO has the fields in the correct order
    })
    ;


CreateMap<ModelView, Model>()
    .AfterMap((v, m) =>
    {
        //override the sequence values based on the order they were provided in the DTO
        var counter = 0;
        foreach (var field in m.Fields)
        {
            field.Sequence = counter++;
        }
    })
```

Comment: You can use `ReverseMap` instead of adding the second mapping. BTW, your question does not contain definition of `ModelView`, for me, it is a bit hard to understand the requirement.